# Как установить margin? В ConstraintLaoyut

Tags: android

Есть вот такое вью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <ui.customWidgets.circleImageView.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_home_screen_profile"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_prof_image"
    app:civ_border="true"
    app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bv_home_screen"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bv_home_screen"/>
```

Мне нужно , чтоб оно было смещено немного вверх...

Сейчас оно четко по центру, а мне нужно, сместить его вверх, чтоб большая часть была над линеей и меньшая под ней.

Пробую установить марджин, но он не дает еффект когда верх и низ закреплен на одну и тоже точку.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Видать без дополнительной вьюхи не выйдет

Comment: нижний паддинг для маленького изображения поднимает вверх, верхний паддинг - опускает вниз, но это скорее костыль, к тому же размер виджета меняется